# Need help to convert sed script to python script

Tags: python, sed

example sed command:

```
$ echo "/dev/sda1 /dev/xvdb3" | sed -r 's%(/dev/)(xv|s)(d[a-z])[0-9]*%\1(xv|s)\3%g' 
/dev/(xv|s)da /dev/(xv|s)db
```

how to convert it to python code?

tried following code:

```
device = "/dev/sda5"
m = re.match(r"(/dev/)(xv|s)(d[a-z])", device)
print m.group(0)
```

got error:

```
print m.group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: I'd like to help you getting rid of `sed` in favor of python, but it's really too broad and a "write code for me" request. I cannot condone that sorry.

Comment: `sed` is just a manipulation tool that uses regex. Consider using the `re` library along with `re.compile`, `re.search`/`re.match`, and `re.sub`

Comment: Just a hint: `sed` reads one line at a time, apply transformations on it (here a single regex based substitution) and outputs the line. The python conversion will be a script that: 1/ read lines from standard input (`for line in sys.stdin:`), 2/ apply a substitution (use the `re` module) and 3/ output the changed line (`print` or `sys.stdout.write`). Write some code and feel free to ask a more precise question if stuck somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

```
re.match(r"(/dev/)(xv|s)(d[a-z])", device)
```

won't work because you need to escape the parentheses in `(xv|s)`. Plus `match` only tries to match at the start of the string. You want `re.sub` to mimic `sed`

Anyway, it's very easy to convert the `sed` command. Just split according to `%` in your pattern and use a raw string prefix for the replacement for `\1` and such (or python escape sequences get in the way)

so with your exact search & replace expressions:

```
re.sub("(/dev/)(xv|s)(d[a-z])[0-9]*",r"\1(xv|s)\3","/dev/sda1 /dev/xvdb3")
```

prints:

```
/dev/(xv|s)da /dev/(xv|s)db
```

Comment: This is exactly what I looking for. Thanks a lot!